# How do I cancel/void an order using Paypal API V2?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

What is the equivalent to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#orders_cancel in the V2 of Paypal API?

After an order has been Authorised (using API v2 authorize request with 'CREATED' response), I want the user to be able to cancel it after the click of a button. That button runs a cancel() method.

So my question is, what request should I put in the cancel method to cancel/void the existing order using the orderID? I know I could just leave the order be in V2, but I specifically want to void/cancel it.
(Also, I can only use post, put and patch requests with the implementation I've been given)

Would really appreciate it if you could provide the curl command or nodeJS fetch implementation for it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the v2 order was `intent:'authorize'` and you 'COMPLETED' it to get back an authorization object, you can void the authorization using the [v2/payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_void).

If, however, the order was merely 'CREATED' or 'APPROVED', there is no way to cancel or void it. Simply have your system forget about it.

Comment: Thank you again! Just read that I need to send a save request before I can send the void request. Tried to send a save request, got "The option to save an order is only available if the `intent` is AUTHORIZE and `processing_instruction` is ORDER_SAVED_EXPLICITLY." I tried including that in save request's body but that didn't work. Do I need to include that in the body of authorize request I'm sending or do I need to send those at the time of order creation?

Comment: Make sure you are voiding the payment authorization id, not the order id

Answer (score 0):

You can't using V2 but V1 API is still available so you can use that API.

Python 3.x sample:

```py
    import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    
    def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret):
        res = requests.post(
            'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            headers={
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            },
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret),
            data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
        ).json()
        return res['access_token']
    
    
    def cancel_order(access_token, order_id) -> bool:
        uri = f'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/{order_id}'
        res = requests.delete(
            uri,
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
            }
        )
    
        if not res.ok:
            raise Exception(f"\n\nPayPal API Call failed for url {uri}: {res.reason} ({res.text}).\nFull Response:\n{res}\n\n")
    
        return
    
    
    acc_token = get_access_token('<<client_id>>', '<<client_secret>>')
    cancel_order(acc_token, '<<order_id>>')
```